# How to use implementation 'com.jjoe64:graphview:4.2.2'

Tags: android

Do I need a kind of lisence to use implementation 'com.jjoe64:graphview:4.2.2' in my build.gradle?
If yes how can implement a lisence in my code?

Comment: Did you see a license error code in your console? Did you run into any errors?

Comment: No my app runs without an error. I'm only afraid to upload it because I thought maybe I need a lisence to use  'com.jjoe64:graphview:4.2.2'

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Questions about licensing are better suited for [Open Source](http://opensource.stackexchange.com/) site

Answer (score 0):

Based on the information from the [Chart and Graph Library for Android](https://github.com/jjoe64/GraphView), the project is licensed under the [APACHE LICENSE, VERSION 2.0](https://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0) license.

You may use the library as per the limits and regulations stated in that license. You neither need to manually add the license into your project nor implement it in code.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I've read the APACHE LICENSE, VERSION 2.0 and I felt a bit insecure. I thought maybe I have to mention somewhere that I use 'com.jjoe64:graphview:4.2.2'.  When I read this kind of documents I'm not always sure about if I understand it right.